# Numpy Array Matrix Stacking

Tags: arrays, numpy, stack

I have 3 numpy arrays -

XX, XY, YY , each having a shape of (200, 300)

I'm trying to stack an array of shape 200x300x2x2

> [ XX, XY
>     XY, YY ]

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Matrices are 2d. Are you trying to build a 4d array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
np.dstack((xx, xy, xy, yy)).reshape(200, 300, 2, 2)
```